# How to run airflow dag Tuesday through Sunday

Tags: cron, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have an airflow running in cloud composer, I want to run the dag everyday except mondays.

I have setup my dag as follows but it didn't run on Tuesday.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'name',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email': ['my_email@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'retries': 3,  
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=0.5),
    'catchup': False
}

@dag(schedule_interval='00 04 * * 2-7', default_args=default_args)
def my_dag():
   ...
```

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cron expressions, the days are numbered 0-6, not 1-7, so you would need to account for that.
It seems that looping around like "2-0" doesn't seem to work, so I am solving this this by creating a comma-separated list, which also has better readability:

```
@dag(schedule_interval='0 4 * * 2,3,4,5,6,0', default_args=default_args)
```

Double check via Crontabguru:

- https://crontab.guru/#0_4_*_*_2,3,4,5,6,0